# How to populate several QComboBox from a QFileSystemModel?

Tags: python, pyqt

How does one use a QFileSystemModel to populate several QComboBox with subdirectories?

I have built a project management tool that allows me to create and manage my projects. I am currently using a combination of os.listdir and json to populate and validate my QComboboxes. But I am trying to learn a more modelview approach with QFileSystemModel.

So this is what I have:

```
class FileSystemModel(QW.QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        QW.QFileSystemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.root = root
        self.rootIndex = self.setRootPath(root)

class Window(QW.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        layout = QW.QVBoxLayout()

        self.cbox = QW.QComboBox()
        self.cbox2 = QW.QComboBox()

        self.model = FileSystemModel("C:\\projects\\")
        self.cbox.setModel(self.model)
        self.cbox2.setModel(self.model)
        self.cbox.setRootModelIndex(self.model.rootIndex)

        self.cbox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._indexChanged)

        layout.addWidget(self.cbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.cbox2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _indexChanged(self):
        row = self.sender().currentIndex()
        index = self.sender().rootModelIndex().child(row, 0)
        self.cbox2.setRootModelIndex(index)


def main():
    app = QW.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was attempting to repopulate the cbox2 using the index from cbox, but with my code it doesn't seem to work - it just stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is modified version of what you had:

```
from sys import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore    import QDir, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileSystemModel, QHBoxLayout, QComboBox

class SysDirModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, DirPath):
        QFileSystemModel.__init__(self)

        self.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
      # Property
        self.setRootPath(DirPath)
      # Property
        self.RootIndex = self.index(DirPath)

class SysFileModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, DirPath):
        QFileSystemModel.__init__(self)

        self.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Files)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
      # Property
        self.setRootPath(DirPath)
      # Property
        self.RootIndex = self.index(DirPath)

    def ResetPath(self, DirPath):
        self.setRootPath(DirPath)
        self.RootIndex = self.index(DirPath)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 450, 100)

      # If you use forward slash this works in Windows as well and it is cleaner
        self.SysDirs = SysDirModel('C:/projects/')
        self.SysFils = SysFileModel('C:/projects/')
      # Setup first ComboBox
        self.cbxDirs = QComboBox()
        self.cbxDirs.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.cbxDirs.setModel(self.SysDirs)
        self.cbxDirs.setRootModelIndex(self.SysDirs.RootIndex)
      # This sends a Signal to a predefined Slot
        self.cbxDirs.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.IndexChanged)

        self.cbxFiles = QComboBox()
        self.cbxFiles.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.cbxFiles.setModel(self.SysFils)
        self.cbxFiles.setRootModelIndex(self.SysFils.RootIndex)

        HBox = QHBoxLayout()
        HBox.addWidget(self.cbxDirs)
        HBox.addStretch(1)
        HBox.addWidget(self.cbxFiles)

        self.setLayout(HBox)

  # This is the receiver of a Signal (aka Slot) so it ought to be used as such
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def IndexChanged(self, RowIdx):
      # Get your Current DirPath based on the Selected Value
        index = self.cbxDirs.rootModelIndex().child(RowIdx, 0)
        DirPath = self.cbxDirs.model().filePath(index)
      # Reset what ComboBox 2's Model and what it is looking at 
        self.cbxFiles.clear()
        self.SysFils.ResetPath(DirPath)
        self.cbxFiles.setModel(self.SysFils)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainThred = QApplication([])

    MainGui = MainWindow()
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainThred.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. So there isn't a way to split the model data across multiple views? I would need to implement a separate model for each combo box? In the end I will have 4 x combobox each showing a different branch of the tree.

Comment: Well you could design the Class to be more generic and then apply the filter to it externally but I am not understanding what you mean by having 4 comboboxes each showing a different branch of the tree?  How do you go from one showing the directories and one showing the files (just 2 comboboxes) to 4 comboboxes what other branches are you talking about?

Comment: Also why are you not using a TreeView for this?

Comment: Hi Dennis thanks again for commenting. So I don't think I've explained my issue correctly. I know the most common use of the FileSystemModel is to display folders in one view and files in another. I however just want to display the folders, similarly to a tree, but represented as a combobox for each branch of the tree. This is purely a design choice.

Comment: Well there is no way to get around needing to use separate filters but like I said you could make the above 2 classes more generic -- by like maybe passing in a variable and setting up the filters inside of an if statement -- or something like that but I am not sure I would do that -- I mean having 4 separate classes for the 4 separate objects means that if should you want to change something in one you will not affect the other 3 at all in anyway -- but totally up to you on that one